# Baud rate for at89c2051 using 24 MHz oscillator

Tags: microcontroller, baudrate

What is baud rate of AT89C2051 using 24 MHz crystal oscillator in Timer 0 mode?

I have seen [this post](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/14089/baud-rate-for-8051-microcontroller) about calculating baud rate of microcontroller but I don't understand it.

How to find / set baud rate in AT89C2051?

Comment: What does the datasheet say?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams its available [here](http://www.atmel.com/images/doc0368.pdf) but it doesnt say anything about baud rate

Answer (score 2):

If you click on [the "Documents" tab](http://www.atmel.com/devices/at89c2051.aspx?tab=documents) and scroll down, you'll find a... UGH, FRIGGING EXCEL FILE that gives the [register values for various frequencies and baud rates](http://www.atmel.com/Images/UART_timer1_2_ibrg_RevB.xls).

Comment: i didnt know there was a documents tab...navigation on that site sent me to list of microcontroller and their pdf datasheet! by the way the site is under maintanence...thanks anyway.